# grails datePicker data binding

Tags: data-binding, grails, datepicker

I've create a modified version of Grails' datePicker tag. It uses exactly the same parameters as the Grails datePicker, but for some reason the `Date` property of the object that these parameters are bound to is not being set.

This class has a property `start` of type `Date` and the parameters that are being sent are

- start_year
- start_month
- start_day
- start_hour
- start_minute

which are exactly the same as those used by the Grails datePicker. Is there a reason why these would bind to a Date property when the Grails datePicker is used, but not mine?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra field hidden called "start" with the value "date.struct" otherwise Grails will not recognize your date fields. Check out the <g:dateField> output, to see all the fields needed.

/Søren

Comment: The hidden field should ofcourse be named, whatever your Date field in your domain/command object is named.

Comment: hmmm. odd. Because I have made a small taglib for a jQuery date-picker and it works. At some point I plan to release it, but for now, please let me know if you want the code